# Java 8: Static helpers vs default methods for common test assertions

Tags: java, unit-testing

I've been doing TDD in Java on quite a few projects and I always have to deal with a situation where I share some common assertions between certain tests. My pre-Java 8 solution would always look like this.

A class with common assertions and static methods:

```
class CommonAssertions {
  static void assertCorrectUser(User user) {
    // bunch of assertions
  }
}
```

Used like this:

```
class FooTest {
  @Test
  void somethingToDoWithUser() {
    User user = // obtain user somehow
    CommonAssertions.assertCorrectUser(user);
  }
}
```

now with Java 8 I am tempted to use interface with `default` methods for common assertions:

```
interface CommonAssertions {
  default assertCorrectUser(User user) {
    // bunch of assertions on user
  }
}
```

then instead of static calls I'd design my tests like so:

```
class FooTest implements CommonAssertions { ... }
```

It's pretty similar, but it seems that the second one is easier to use (saves bunch of static imports) and reveals more about the test. Image code like:

`class CompanyResourceTest implements UserAssertions, CompanyAssertions, JsonErrorAssertions { ... }`

Some might argue that `default` was designed for something completely different, and this is a misuse. Some might argue that this is as bad as putting bunch of constants into an `interface` and implementing it. But is there really any **drawback** in this approach?

Comment: This is a variant on the [constant interface antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface). Avoid it at all costs. A `default` method should be a sensible default implementation of something that belongs in the `interface`. Use `static` utility methods, and `import static` to remove the class names.

Comment: Just static import the methods if you don't want to be wordy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawback is that is unclear. An interface is a contract where implementation details are not specified. By just having all default methods, you're abusing what an interface was designed for, which generally makes code harder to understand by others. Java is limited in the sense that it doesn't support mixins or traits, and using default interfaces for this is just a hacky way around it.

Static methods are the norm for this in java, but if you're really opposed to them,  I would suggest a couple of alternatives:

- Write your tests in a language that supports mixins, such as groovy
  or scala
- Create a common base test class of yours, such as UserTest and have your user related tests extend that. Not ideal, especially if you would need multiple inheritance.
- Write annotations that can inject those methods in your test, so you could have @UserTest that would compile in those methods.